# How can I push my local branch to a different remote tracking branch?

Tags: git

I have been doing my development on my own local branch. I have been doing a lot of commits on it. How can I push all my commits to a different remote tracking branch (different the branch my local branch created from)?

Answer (score 3):

`git push local_branch:remote_branch`

Answer (score 1):

```
git push origin localbranch:remotebranch
```

But it may be better to first fetch changes that happened on the remote branch, merge  the local branch into it, and then push it.